# Binding list of object to datagridview but only show specific elements of that list

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hey im trying to bind a list to a datagridview. The list have 5 elements (ID, Name, amount, amount2, amount3)

I can bind the list to datagridview to show the whole but i only want to show ID, name and amount2 on the datagridview. How do i do this?

```
BL.Controller.KontoController kc = new BL.Controller.KontoController();
public Cost()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = kc.GetallID();




    }
```

Comment: Solved it! i just put columns.visible = false;

Comment: **1)** You can set `Visible` property of those specific columns to `false`. **2)** Using linq, you can shape the list to a `List<ViewModel>` containing just properties which you want to show. **3)** If the model is just created to be used in UI layer, you can decorate some properties with `[Browsabe(false)]` attribute to prevent showing them in `DataGridView`.